Understanding deep learning notation and properties of expectation - neighbor2neighbor
I am trying to follow the proof of Theorem 1 here but can't fully understand the notation the authors use so that I am not able to completely understand the steps. This misunderstanding keeps coming up when I try diving into details of some proofs from the deep learning community.
My questions are:

(1) The authors start with $\mathbb{E}_{x,y} ||f_\theta(y)-x||_2^2 $. What is the formal definition of this expression? Is it $\sum ||f_\theta(y_i)-x_i||_2^2 p(x_i,y_i)$ where $p$ is the joint distribution of $x$ and $y$?
(2) In the first step, the authors use $\mathbb{E}_{y|x} ||f_\theta(y)-x ||_2^2= \mathbb{E}_{y,z|x} ||f_\theta(y)-z+z-x ||_2^2$. Is there any way to explain this step using the definition of conditional expectation? I can't understand how could they just add $z$ to the distribution once they added and subtracted it in the norm?
(3) Given the two questions above, you might have a better idea on my misunderstanding the notation. Do you have any recommendations for a book/paper/youtube that covers these from scratch? I do have a background in probability theory, but still can't follow the steps they're taking.

Thank you


Yes for the first part.

For the second part, let me be abstract to work beyond the quantity of your interest, let $A(x,y)=f_{\theta}(y)-x$.


We have the following identity:
$$P(y|x) =\sum_z P(z,y|x)$$
Thus,
\begin{align}E_{y|x}(A(x,y)) &= \sum_{y} A(x,y) P(y|x)\\&=\sum_{y} A(x,y) \sum_z P(y,z|x)\\&=\sum_{y,z}A(x,y) P(y,z|x)\\
&=E_{y,z|x} A(x,y) \\
&= E_{y,z|x} [A(x,y)+z-z]\end{align}

Just read more on probability theory and work on more exercises, no particular boo in particular.


Thank you for that @Siong Thye Goh! Is there any chance you'll also be able to help me understand how they obtained $var(z)=\mathbb{E}_{z|x} ||z-x||^2$? As far as I can understand, $var(z)= \mathbb{E}_z [(z-E(z))^T (z-E(z)]$,, i.e. with respect to the distribution of $z$ and not $z|x$. Thank you!

Also, isn't the definition of $\mathbb{E}{y|x } A(x,y) = \sum{y} A(x,y)P(y|x)$? that's the definition I am use to, and it seems like this is not the case here.

yikes, I made a mistake.

Thank you for clarifying this @Siong! Is there any chance you'll be able to help me figure out the variance of z part I asked about? I will of course accept your answer even if not. Thank you!

i'm still thinking for that part.

Thank you. I accepted your answer in the meantime. Hope you'll also be able to help me with my last question on the variance. Thank you again!

I think the definition is unclear, $z$ is an image, what does it mean by a variance of an image, is it an image? From the working, it is a number. What we know that is $E_{z|x}(z) = x+\epsilon$ where $x$ is given and $\epsilon$ is the only source of uncertainty. $E_{z|x}(z-x) =\epsilon$,  $E_{z|x}(|z-x|^2)=E_{z|x}(|\epsilon|^2)$ and it seems that they call this term $\sigma_z^2$.

Thank you so much for that! Indeed, this is something I also failed to understand... Have no idea what's their definition for variance of an image. Anyway, you helped me more than enough. Thank you!
